# ember-cli-live-reload Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Anyone else getting this warning in their browser console? It's always on the first line when the page first loads.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <          ember-cli-live-reload.js:1
```

My stack:

```
 DEBUG: -------------------------------
ember.js:3935 DEBUG: Ember                     : 1.9.1
ember.js:3935 DEBUG: Ember Data                : 1.0.0-beta.14.1
ember.js:3935 DEBUG: Handlebars                : 2.0.0
ember.js:3935 DEBUG: jQuery                    : 1.11.2
ember.js:3935 DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth         : 0.7.2
ember.js:3935 DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth Testing : 0.7.2
ember.js:3935 DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Comment: I get basically the same when F12 (Developer Tools) are open and the page first loads, or reloads after i update a file.

Answer (score 2):

This has usually been due to improper commenting out of handlebars with html somewhere in a template.

I had:

```
<!-- <hr>
{{#link-to 'job-applications.job-application' profile class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-outline" tagName='button'}}View Full Application{{/link-to}} -->
```

Which was causing the issue. Should remove all non-used handlebars or at least not mix html & handlebars in comments.

Comment: This was the case for me as well. I commented out the vendor.css in my index.html with standard HTML comments. I didn't think it would matter because it wasn't .hbs.  : ) Thanks!